# How to use Telerik Fiddler REGEX to replace Server JS-file with local one?

Tags: python, regex, url, fiddler

There is a JS-file with the following structure:
https://sub-domain.domain.com/pa-th/subpath/v1/js/jsfile.js?_=1481126808853

and I'm using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger v4.6.3.44034 to filter that URL with a regex. But it always fails.

within the Autoresponder Tab I added a Rule with following content:

```
REGEX:https://sub-domain\.domain\.de/pa-th/subpath/v1/js/jsfile\.js(.*)
```

I tried various configurations including masking the Slashes and adding a masked question mark, tried masking the hyphens etc. but none of it did replace the file. What is the correct way to do it? It seems I can't even test the regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) because it seems to be a python regex in Fiddler but slightly different from normal python regex patterns and the research was even more confusing because it seems that different Fiddler versions use different Regex patterns. Can anyone provide a solution or some tips maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is looking for .de, but your URL is .com    On regex101.com this is a match:

URL text

```
https://sub-domain.domain.com/pa-th/subpath/v1/js/jsfile.js?_=1481126808853
```

Regex

```
https://sub-domain\.domain\.com/pa-th/subpath/v1/js/jsfile\.js(.*)
```

I don't recall what regex language Fiddler uses, but you may need to escape the forward slashes as well, like

```
https:\/\/sub-domain\.domain\.com\/pa-th\/subpath\/v1\/js\/jsfile\.js(.*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile I figured it out. It was not about the top-level dmain. I just made a mistake when changing the url. I figured out that there is a test button in Fiddler where I could test the regex. I just overlooked it.